# ProFTPd login issue after changing users homedir with usermod

Tags: ftp

If I create a new user with

```
$ sudo adduser testuser
```

I can perfectly login via ProFTPd with this user but as soon as I change the users homedir with

```
$ sudo usermod -d /path/to/newdir testuser
```

I can't login anymore. Also if I create a new user and change the users homedir to the original homedir (so I basically leave it unchanged) it wont work:

```
$ sudo adduser testuser
Adding user 'testuser' ...
[...]
```

Now the users homedir is /home/testuser and I can login. If I run now this command:

```
$ sudo usermod -d /home/testuser testuser
```

I can't login anymore. The message log is:

```
Answer:  220 ProFTPD 1.3.1 Server (ProFTPD) [*.*.*.*]
Command: USER testuser
Answer:  331 Password required for testiser
Command: PASS **********
Answer:  530 Login incorrect.
```

I double and triple checked the password, it is 100% correct (I can't misspell asdf ...)

So now I don't know what to do. My proftpd.conf looks like this:

```
ServerName                      "ProFTPD"
ServerType                      standalone
DefaultServer                   on

DefaultRoot     ~               psacln
AllowOverwrite          on

DefaultTransferMode     binary
UseFtpUsers                     on
TimesGMT                        off
SetEnv TZ :/etc/localtime
Port                            21
Umask                           022
MaxInstances                    30
ScoreboardFile /var/run/proftpd_scoreboard
TransferLog /opt/psa/var/log/xferlog

        GroupOwner      psacln

AuthPAM on
AuthPAMConfig proftpd
IdentLookups off
UseReverseDNS off
AuthGroupFile   /etc/group
Include /etc/proftpd.include
```

The proftpd.include is empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Dist. is Linux Debian 2.6.24-etchnhalf.1-686

Answer (score 0):

Caching? Have you restarted proFTPD?